# convert List<Object> to List<HashMap<String,Double>> for a json array

Tags: java, json

I have a Json as shown below:-

```
 {
      "componentModelData": {
        "modelNumber": "ABC",
        "modelName": "",
        "modelDescription": "",
        "modelVendor": null,
        "componentName": "HELO"
      },
      "revisionData": {
        "revisionName": "rev12",
        "revisionComment": "Comment",
        "modifiedBy": "2323553"
      }, 
      "configData": [{"nodes":2085,"FxPOS-SX":16.5051,"FxPOS-SY":11.0479,"FxPOS-SZ":115.3421,"FxPOS-SXY":-13.8094,"FxPOS-SYZ":36.0105
      },{"nodes":2085,"FxPOS-SX":16.5051,"FxPOS-SY":11.0479,"FxPOS-SZ":115.3421,"FxPOS-SXY":-13.8094,"FxPOS-SYZ":36.0105}]
    }
```

DataMapping.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonSerialize
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataMapping implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2635323042843403966L;
    @JsonProperty("componentModelData")
    @Valid
    public ComponentModelDTO componentModelDTO;
    @JsonProperty("revisionData")
    @Valid
    public RevisionDTO revisionDTO;
    @JsonProperty("configData")
    private List<Object> configData;
}
```

I want to convert the configData list to `List<HashMap<String,Double>> list` where String is the keys like 'nodes,FxPOS-SX,FxPOS-SY' and value is their respective values.

Can anyone please help me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `List<Object>` with `List<Map<String,Double>>`. Jackson will do the hard work for you:

```
@JsonProperty("configData")
private List<Map<String, Double>> configData;
```